# How do you close an ASP.NET MVC page from the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that opens a "Request" view in a new browser window. When the user submits the form, I'd like the window to close. What should my RequestController code look like to close the window after saving the request information? I'm not sure what the controller action should be returning.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could return a View that has the following javascript (or you could return a JavaScript result) but I prefer the former.

```cs
public ActionResult SubmitForm()
{
    return View("Close");
}
```

View for Close:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.close();
    </script>
</body>
```

Here is a way to do it directly in your Controller but I advise against it

```
public ActionResult SubmitForm()
{
    return JavaScript("window.close();");
}
```

Comment: Curious: why would you advise against the controller-only solution?

Comment: You're manipulating the UI by closing a window.  Doesn't seem like a controller responsibility.

Comment: I just tried to return the JavaScript and it doesn't work. It only displays "window.close();" on the screen. I read somewhere else that you should call this action using Ajax but I haven't been able to test it. Just giving the heads up.

Comment: You can't close a window using window.close(). You will get "Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it."

Answer (score 3):

Like such:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyController(Model model)
{
    //do stuff
    ViewBag.Processed = true;
    return View();
}
```

The view:

```
<%if(null!=ViewBag.Processed && (bool)ViewBag.Processed == true){%>
<script>
    window.close();
</script>
<%}%>
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you could return an almost empty View template that simply had some javascript in the header that just ran "window.close()".

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Done()
{
    return Content(@"<body>
                       <script type='text/javascript'>
                         window.close();
                       </script>
                     </body> ");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can close by this code:

```
return Content(@"<script>window.close();</script>", "text/html");
```

Comment: Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to close the window.

Controller:

```
 return PartialView("_LoginSuccessPartial");
```

View:

```
<script>
   var loginwindow = $("#loginWindow").data("kendoWindow");
   loginwindow.close();
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using this you can close the window like this:

```
return Content("&lt;script language='javascript'>window.close();&lt;/script>");
```

Comment: For me, this just returned the script as a string and displayed it, not run it.

Comment: return Content("<script type='text/javascript'>window.close();</script>");