# How to close window on browser (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Good day!

EDIT: 
I have simple static site and script in it: when i press Cntrl-Enter- open popup window.And then after press -Submit- i send post request into my mvc app.

I write simple asp mvc app , result of it work- send message at opened popup window:All done.Press button to close it".

Return result into this window:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";
        Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
        Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        Response.Expires = -1;
        Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

        return View();
    }
```

How i try to close this window on client:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function OnCloseForm()
{

    this.window.close();
}
```

But i cant do that!
I know,that i should use window.open() and then i can do window.close().
But how to close popup window at my case?

Thank you!

P.S. Unfortunatelly- window.close() not works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to close current tab in a browser window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853738/how-do-you-close-an-asp-net-mvc-page-from-the-controller)

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.close();
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just call `window.close()` (without the this in front)